# php sessions destroyed instantly

Tags: php, session

It seems that sessions work when I set them for an instant, and then they are destroyed.
Here is my phpinfo page, can anyone see the problem?
I don't have access to the phpini file.
Can you check my cookie settings and tell me if I can use those instead?
http://cksgrill.net/phpinfo.php

```
[code]

<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="/javascript/header.js"></script>
<?

session_set_cookie_params(3000); 
session_start();
ob_start();
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 6 * 60 * 60);
$session_expiration = time() + 3600 * 24 * 2;
if((($_POST['name'])and($_POST['password']))or(($_POST['name']!="")and($_POST['password']!="")))
{
    $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['password']=$_POST['password'];
    echo $_SESSION['name'];
    echo $_POST['name'];
    echo $_SESSION['password'];
    echo $_POST['password'];
}


// redifine variables for different server
require_once "mysqlconfig.php";  
require_once "textprep.php";  

// connect to database
global $connection;
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS); 
if (!$connection)
{
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

// select database
$db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connection);
if (!$db_select)
{
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

//check if logged in
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin");
if (!$result)
{
    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
}

// get table names as mysql feedback
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $name[$i]=$row['name'];
    $password[$i]=$row['password'];
    $rank[$i]=$row['rank'];

    //echo "\$name[$i]=".$row['name'];
    //echo "\$password[$i]=".$row['password'];
    //echo "\$rank[$i]=".$row['rank'];

    $i++;
}

//check if logged in
$log=false;
for($j=0;$j<$i;$j++)
{
    //echo "<p>(".$name[$j]."==".$_SESSION['name'].")and(".$password[$j]."==".$_SESSION['password'].")</p>";
    if(($name[$j]==$_SESSION['name'])and($password[$j]==$_SESSION['password']))
    {
        $log=true;
        echo logged." ".$log;
    }
}
if($log==true)
{
[/code]
```

Comment: AFAIK, Your PHP info file is good. Can we see your code ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php this may help you set your own time for expiration.

Comment: ok, but i think u can solve the problem with just the php info, i see cashe size set to 0 and cokie time set to 0, so i think thats the problem but im not sure. the code is awfully big but ill try posting it
edit: ya this site will not allow me to pose the code

Comment: ok i figued out how to show my code! but people have stopped answering :( i think ill repost, i hope the admins dont get mad

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code below session_start();

```
<?php session_start();
ob_start();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

YOU can increase your session default timeout by using

```
      session_set_cookie_params(3000); 

   Then start your session this will allow you to increase session timout you
   don't have to edit php.ini
```

Comment: ok heres the start of my code, i treid adding your solutions but the sessions are still destroyed after 1 page load
[code]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="/javascript/header.js"></script>
<?
session_start();
ob_start();
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 6 * 60 * 60);
$session_expiration = time() + 3600 * 24 * 2;
session_set_cookie_params(3000); 
[/code]

Comment: session_set_cookie_params(3000); then session_start() try this

Comment: yes i tried that, i realized my mistake after posting. its still not working tho. i sure wish i could post more of my code. here is how i am setting the session variables, if the use logs in there is a post if((($_POST['name'])and($_POST['password']))or(($_POST['name']!="")and($_POST['password']!="")))
{
 $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
 $_SESSION['password']=$_POST['password'];

Comment: Try your code by removing these two code lines  ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 6 * 60 * 60);
 $session_expiration = time() + 3600 * 24 * 2; as session_set_cookie_params(3000); also doing the same thing.

Comment: i tried removing those lines and replacing them with sesson set cookie params, still the session is destroyed after 1 page load